# Stanford NLP POS Tagger has issues with very simple phrases?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics, part-of-speech

I found examples of inconsistent behavior in my application using Stanford NLP Parser/POS Tagger and I was able to replicate it online http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process . I am using version 3.60:

Here are the 3 issues I have found so far:

- Dot with or without inconsistency problem:

[image: NLP Stanford POS Tagger with and without dot]

- Verbs that are found as Nouns
  [image]
- Verbs that are tagged as Adjectives
  [image]

I know that language is fairly ambiguous but I would like to know if I can trust this library even for those simple phrases. I would like to also know if I am doing something wrong. I tried the problematic cases of each of an example alone or in other words in separate sentences and the problem persists.

This is the expected behavior:

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Put a space before fullstop?

Comment: @alvas I just tried and it doesn't change the behavior of any of the problems related to the fullstop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. You're of course welcome to decide for yourself how much to trust any tool, but I suspect you'll see similar issues with any parser trained empirically/statistically. As to your issues:

- Periods are treated like any other token in model building, so, yes, they can influence the parse chosen.
- There are indeed a lot of ambiguities in English (as there are in all other human languages), and the question of whether to interpret forms ending in *ing* as verbs, nouns (verbal nouns or gerunds), or adjectives is a common one. The parser does not always get it right.
- In terms of particular bad choices it made, often they reflect usage/domain mismatches between the parser training data and the sentences you are trying. The training data is predominantly news articles – last millennium news articles for that matter – although we do mix in some other data and occasionally add to it. So:

  - The use of *flagging* as a verb, common in modern internet developer use, doesn't occur at all in the training data, so it not surprisingly tends to choose JJ for *flagging*, since that's the analysis of the only cases in the training data.
  - In news articles *drinking* is just more commonly a noun, with discussions of *underage drinking*, *coffee drinking*, *drinking and driving*, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer Prof. Manning :) - I was assuming that shorter phrase results would be more predictable but it seems as if training data is not matching my own data. I will investigate in how I can train the parser myself. Is it a process that requires a lot of effort as I am reading?

Answer (score 1):

The different results from POS taggers was driving me crazy so for sanity checks I finally wrote something to quickly compare results against the three to typically use (Stanford NLP, NLTK 3.2.1 and Senna)
It also times them as often one tagger can choke on certain text.
https://github.com/StealthyK/TaggerTimer